# Passing a function out of a struct to a function

Tags: c++, boost

How do I make this work? The error I'm seeing is 
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <boost\function.hpp>

int AddVariables(boost::function<int(int, int)>func, int a, int b)
{
    return func(a, b);
}

struct TestStruct
{
    void Run()
    {
        AddVariables(&TestStruct::Function1, 2, 3);
    }

    int Function1(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b; 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Function1` is a member function so you need a `this` pointer to call it. Use `bind` to make a functor that automatically applies the `this` pointer:

```
AddVariables(boost::bind(&TestStruct::Function1, this, _1, _2), 2, 3);
```